# twitter status message update through bot using php and twitter oauth

Tags: php, twitter, oauth, bots

I have followed the steps defined in the following link for twitter oauth implementation.

**https://docs.google.com/View?docID=dcf2dzzs_2339fzbfsf4**

Its working fine when i run through web browser but i want a user should be able to update status of twitter account through gmail chat i.e. he should only be authenticated once through web then he should be able to send the status message through gmail chat and his twitter account should be updated

How can i inegrate this because gmail id can be different from twitter id?

Please guide.

Comment: Hi, yeh its working i made a mistake while writing the url now i have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

When you authenticate with twitter using oauth your given credentials you can store and use later when posting updates.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply but can you elaborate on this. How can i store this data and use it later in my code. It would be better if you can share some example code.

Comment: You can sort these details in a cookie for example

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library,

http://emmense.com/php-twitter/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This might be help, I also face the same issue before, and it is now solved.

http://ruckuus.wordpress.com/2009/09/04/pecl-and-twitter-oauth/

Basically, after you ask a grant from user, then you access /access_token you will get authenticated oauth_token, and oauth_token_secret which is persistent. so further on you don't need access to access_token anymore if you already had these variables.

Storing it is very simple, either to put them in database, cookies (if you use web application) or in a plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

This article had everything I needed to set up a Twitter-posting bot that authenticates with OAuth: http://masnun.com/blog/2010/04/30/setting-up-twitter-bots-with-oauth/